# How to update facebook profile basic information in php

Tags: php, facebook

I am stuck in problem and not getting any solution. I want to update facebook user profile basic information like (hometown, about, date of birth etc...),

I am getting user information with this code:

```
$fql = "select name from user where uid = me()";

$status1 = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' =>$fql));
```

but now i want to update name of this user using any fb method or fb php api.

I've just tried this method for update

```
$fqlupd = "update user set name = 'Saad Yousaf Updated' where uid = me()";
$status1 = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query','query' =>$fqlupd));
```

but fql query showing error on update query.

kindly tell me any other solution.

I am using facebook php API

I am waiting for reply

Regard

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to modify user name, or other informations, you can only publish to wall if you have permissions, act as user like creating events, add new picture, album, or videos.

For profile basic information you can use FQL or Graph API to get the wanted information.

Check this URL for more information :
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/